# Password se ve en la consola del navegador

Tags: javascript, php, html5

estoy desarrollando un sistema donde la seguridad es mas importante de lo normal, por esto he tenido que implementar varias medidas para evitar o minimizar cualquier tipo de ataque, hasta ahora me ha ido bien.
Utilizo MVC y POO en PHP y me he dado cuenta que cada vez que el sistema llama al Controlador de la validación del login (Utilizo fetch de JavaScript), en la pestaña **Network** de la consola, se ve claramente el password (como se observa en la imagen).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He buscado en internet con respecto al tema, qué se puede hacer para evitar ésta situación pero no he podido conseguir información relevante, mucho agradecería la ayuda.

Comment: Simple no envíes el password al navegador, en lugar de eso recibe el password(introducido por el usuario) desde el navegador y revisa que sea igual al password real desde el servidor y si lo es envías una id=aleatoria+name-user y lo guardas en el navegador y el servidor, si el cliente tiene esa id+name entonces tiene la sección abierta. Nota: No se casi nada de ciberseguridad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respuesta corta: No hay manera

Seguramente tienes un input del tipo password

```
<input type="password" />
```

Esto no es más que in input text que oculta en la vista los caracteres, nada más. Es solo para evitar que alguien que esté viendo el monitor vea tu contraseña. Salvo esto, para todos los efectos es un texto plano, no se encripta la información y nada parecido

El payload es la información que se envía a tu servidor en el POST el cual la toma antes de hacer el submit. Toda esta información viaja desencriptada, a menos que uses https.

Tu perfectamente podría encriptar el password antes de enviarlo y desencriptarlo en el servidor, pero el método estaría en el cliente y esto es un loop infinito de seguridad.

Por mi parte, no veo problema de seguridad en que se muestre en la consola. Es más acabo de probar en 2 bancos distinto y en el payload se muestra la contraseña, tal cual como en tu caso

Answer (score 0):

Esa situación es normal, todo dato debe poder visualizarse para hacer un seguimiento, sea post, get, put. Ahora, podrías utilizar alguna especie de cifrado si no deseas que se vea los datos del password.