# ¿Cómo poner credenciales en archivo .js sin que se vea en el inspector del navegador?

Tags: javascript, php, chrome, mqtt

Estoy desarrollando un programa en PHP pero que utiliza algunas funciones en javascript. El caso es que tengo la siguiente función en javascript donde se indican unos datos de conexión MQTT. Y claro, cuando miramos el código desde el navegador se pueden ver estas credenciales.

```
    function MQTTconnect() {
            var clientID = "clientID-" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100,10);
            console.log("connecting to "+ host +" "+ port);
            mqtt = new Paho.MQTT.Client(host, port, "/ws/mqtt", clientID);
            //document.write("connecting to "+ host);
            var options = {
                useSSL:true,
                timeout: 3,
                onSuccess: onConnect,
                onFailure: onFailure,
                userName: 'ymoohddfdfhh',
                password: 'OoffgMk4VVSO-BXhdfdg9TZBngbjgXj',
                //reconnect: true
 
            };
            mqtt.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived
            mqtt.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
 
            mqtt.connect(options); //connect
        }
```

Cómo podría ocultar la conexión con MQTT? Había pensado en poner de alguna forma los valores en una variable PHP de esta forma:

```
userName: '<?php echo $user ?>',
password: '<?php echo $pass ?>',
```

Pero igual se verían desde el navegador. Se pueden llamar estas credenciales de alguna otra forma?

Gracias

Comment: Juraría que lo que pretendes no es posible (Si estoy equivocado que alguien me corrija), tendrías que encriptar las credenciales o usar algún token de acceso/autenticación o algo parecido. Pero todo lo que reciba el cliente es visible.

Comment: No es posible ocultar contenido que está del lado del cliente. Si usas PHP, podrías usar las credenciales desde allí. Por lo general las APIs tienen biblioteca de clientes para usar en el servidor, allí puedes usar tus credenciales con toda seguridad, sin exponerlas del lado del cliente.

Comment: En efecto, `MQTT` te da la posibilidad de conectar del lado del servidor mediante PHP, sólo tienes que instalar [`php-mqtt/client`](https://github.com/php-mqtt/client) vía composer y programar el código de conexión en PHP por supuesto. Revisa también [este post](https://www.emqx.com/en/blog/how-to-use-mqtt-in-php) para más detalles.

Comment: Ese usuario y password son los mismos para todos los usuarios???

Comment: @Yussef Sí, en principio sería igual para todos

Comment: @ADQA Ahí está el problema, cada usuario debería tener su propia cuenta de esa manera es irrelevante si puede ver los datos ya que estos serían los suyos (es como si tu ves la contraseña de tu propio correo, no hay problema con eso).  Por otro lado a mi se me ocurren un par de formas de ocultar esa info al inspector de código, pero no creo que se puedan ocultar al inspector de red, hasta en las web de los bancos aparecen el user y el pass (https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/555200/301324)